# How to create proper "this" object as argument?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a function where I have to pass an Activity object to a method that requires such an argument. Usually in such case I'm supposed to just type "this" and it automatically recognizes which type of object it's supposed to create. But sometimes this doesn't work and it for whatever reason reassings a different type of object than the one that is required. For example, I actually use the exact same method in both of these cases:

```
if (checkLocationPermission(this)){
```

In this first one, the program automatically recognizes "this" as an Activity object. Here's the second one:

```
@Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location == null || !checkLocationPermission(this)){
```

In this case the exact same method recognizes "this" as an OnSuccessListener instead of an Activity.
Another example I have in the same program is one where "this" object is supposed to be a Looper but instead it again gets recognized as an OnSuccessListener:

```
fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,new LocationCallback(),this);
```

I don't know how to actually select the proper type of object for "this" argument since I can only type the same damn word.

---

EDIT:

### Here's the full code. I used Looper.this just so you can find it easier. I also tried with MapsActivity.this and it doesn't work:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000; //Request code to send to Google Play Services
private LocationRequest locationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(10*1000).setFastestInterval(1*1000);
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(){
    if (mMap==null){
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    //setUpMap();

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Location Services Connected");
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    if (checkLocationPermission(this)){
        fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location == null || !checkLocationPermission(MapsActivity.this)){
                    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,new LocationCallback(),Looper.this);
                }
                else{
                    handleNewLocation(location);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
public static boolean checkLocationPermission(Activity activity){
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},0);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location){
    Log.d(TAG,location.toString());
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Location Services suspended. Please reconnect.");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()){
        //Starts an Activity that tries to resolve the error
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.i(TAG,"Location services connection failed code: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()){
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` corresponds to the object in which it is used. `onSuccess` is a method of `OnSuccessListener` class and hence `this` refers to `OnSuccessListener`. You need to use `ActivityName.this`. For example if you activity name is `MainActivity`, then

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(Location location) {
    if (location == null || !checkLocationPermission(MainActivity.this)){
```

Comment: I tried using Activity.this but it says "android.app.Activity" is not an enclosing class.. :/

Comment: Not Activity.this, YourActivityName.this. (YouActivityName is "your activity name", whatever that is)

Comment: Which activity do you have your onSuccess in?

Comment: I'm using the onSuccess method inside the method:public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)

Comment: No i meant what is the Activity name?

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner in Android Studio.. If you mean the class in which I'm using these methods, it's called MapsActvity

Comment: Yes., So you need to use MapsActivity.this

Comment: This works for the Activity case but still doesn't work for the Looper object

Comment: Can you post the complete Looper code

Comment: Sure. I used the Looper.this just so you can find it. I tried with MapsActivity.this aswell
@Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location == null || !checkLocationPermission(MapsActivity.this)){
                        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,new LocationCallback(),Looper.this);
                    }
                    else{
                        handleNewLocation(location);
                    }
                }

Comment: Sorry about the messy paste.. I'll try editing the question

Comment: Post it as edit in your question. Post the complete code, including the part where you create and use the Looper object

Comment: I posted it as an edit. I only use the Looper object in that one instance where "this" is present. I didn't try to create it anywhere else.

Comment: i don't see the looper in your code.. Post the complete code.. A little extra code doesn't hurt anyone (unless you have copyrighted code which i doubt)

Comment: I actually did add an edit.. I edited it again this time by making the text bold. You should definitely see it now. If not I can even screenshot it

Comment: No i meant more code. What is outside onSuccess? You might as well post you complete activity

Comment: Oh right.. sorry. The method is inside another method called onConnected. I updated the code. Again sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Where is you looper?

Comment: You can use MyLooper.this only if your code is inside the Looper class.. Post your complete class so that i get an idea of what you are doing

Comment: I posted the entire code. I hope you will be able to understand everything now.

Comment: Ok i get what you are trying to do. Just beacause `requestLocationUpdates` expects a looper as third parameter doesn't mean you pass `Looper.this`. The third parameter is required only if you are using a `Looper`. In your case you are not, so pass null. `fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,new LocationCallback(),null);`

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use an anonymous inner class, such as a listener, and use `this`, it refers to the anonymous inner class, because that's your current location.

For instance, with an OnClickListener:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //"this" here will refer to the OnClickListener instance you create
    }
}
```

Nothing is being "created" with a `this` argument. It's a direct reference to the current enclosing class. If you need to reference the Activity, you can use:

```
ActivityClassName.this
```

as long as you're in an inner class and not a static class.

If you use a lambda (only available for API 24+):

```
view.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
    //"this" will reference your Activity because there's no inner class anymore
}
```

Comment: The class I'm using is only declared public, not static. I tried passing Activity.this as an argument but it says "android.app.Activity" is not an enclosing class.. :/

Comment: No, you need to use the exact name of the class that encloses it. If it's MainActivity, then you use MainActivity.this.

Answer (score 0):

the `this` refers to the object of the immediate enclosing class. So, if you have some `interface` or `class` as an argument to a function, we usually do like this :

```
functionThatTakesInterfaceOrClassAsArgument( new TheInterfaceOrClass {
    @Override
    public void someMethod () {
        // if you use `this` here, it refers to the object of `TheInterfaceOrClass`
    }

});
```

If you want to use the object corresponding to an enclosing class (yet not the immediate enclosing class) using `<className>.this`

So, if the name of the enclosing `Activity` is `MyActivity`, one would need to use `MyActivity.this`.

Comment: I tried passing Activity.this as an argument but it says "android.app.Activity" is not an enclosing class... :/

Comment: it has to be the name of the class. not `Activity.this`. Read the last line of the answer.